# Can't connect to PostgreSQL many times in Mocha tests

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mocha.js

I'm creating a Node.js server using Express. The server connects to PostgreSQL database. I'm learning to use Mocha for tests, but now the tests timeout in "beforeEach" hook. This is quite strange, because the "beforeEach" hook completes successfully in some `it('should ...')` cases, but timeouts in later cases.

My tests are now in two files: `test/events.js` and `test/announcements.js`. The timeout error occurs only if I run all the tests (both files). If I run these separately, the everything works fine.

Here is what I get when I run the tests separately:

```bash
$ mocha --timeout 30000 "test/announcements.js"

  Announcements
GET /api/announcements/list 200 84.757 ms - 175
    ✓ should GET all the announcements (271ms)
PUT /api/announcements/create 200 116.172 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 18.715 ms - 238
    ✓ should PUT a new announcement (211ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 22.114 ms - 175
POST /api/announcements/edit 200 30.060 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 9.408 ms - 153
    ✓ should POST an edit to existing announcement (108ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 22.030 ms - 175
POST /api/announcements/edit 404 13.532 ms - 49
GET /api/announcements/list 200 18.323 ms - 175
    ✓ should NOT POST an edit to inexisting announcement (152ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 27.353 ms - 175
DELETE /api/announcements/delete 200 15.780 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 10.735 ms - 92
    ✓ should DELETE existing announcement (103ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 20.080 ms - 175
DELETE /api/announcements/delete 404 7.138 ms - 49
GET /api/announcements/list 200 5.113 ms - 175
    ✓ should NOT DELETE inexisting announcement (83ms)


 6 passing (1s)


$ mocha --timeout 30000 "test/announcements.js"

  Events
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 177.934 ms - 109
    ✓ should GET all the events (371ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
PUT /api/events/create 200 109.243 ms - 16
GET /api/events/list 200 10.463 ms - 144
    ✓ should PUT a new event (201ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 7.600 ms - 109
POST /api/events/edit 200 33.369 ms - 16
GET /api/events/list 200 5.774 ms - 97
    ✓ should POST an edit to existing event (89ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 10.483 ms - 109
POST /api/events/edit 404 12.057 ms - 42
GET /api/events/list 200 10.789 ms - 109
    ✓ should NOT POST an edit to inexisting event (99ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 10.907 ms - 109
DELETE /api/events/delete 200 16.145 ms - 16
GET /api/events/list 200 11.006 ms - 63
    ✓ should DELETE existing event (105ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 27.856 ms - 109
DELETE /api/events/delete 404 17.645 ms - 42
GET /api/events/list 200 16.777 ms - 109
    ✓ should NOT DELETE inexisting event (161ms)


  6 passing (2s)
```

But if I run all the tests:

```bash
$ mocha --timeout 30000 "test/announcements.js" "test/events.js"

  Announcements
GET /api/announcements/list 200 84.049 ms - 175
    ✓ should GET all the announcements (270ms)
PUT /api/announcements/create 200 132.603 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 15.295 ms - 238
    ✓ should PUT a new announcement (256ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 32.020 ms - 175
POST /api/announcements/edit 200 24.557 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 7.385 ms - 153
    ✓ should POST an edit to existing announcement (142ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 21.938 ms - 175
POST /api/announcements/edit 404 14.570 ms - 49
GET /api/announcements/list 200 26.202 ms - 175
    ✓ should NOT POST an edit to inexisting announcement (110ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 34.236 ms - 175
DELETE /api/announcements/delete 200 15.140 ms - 16
GET /api/announcements/list 200 10.347 ms - 92
    ✓ should DELETE existing announcement (108ms)
GET /api/announcements/list 200 27.241 ms - 175
DELETE /api/announcements/delete 404 18.707 ms - 49
GET /api/announcements/list 200 5.255 ms - 175
    ✓ should NOT DELETE inexisting announcement (95ms)

  Events
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 122.535 ms - 109
    ✓ should GET all the events (137ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
PUT /api/events/create 200 11.871 ms - 16
GET /api/events/list 200 17.677 ms - 144
    ✓ should PUT a new event (87ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 7.059 ms - 109
POST /api/events/edit 200 9.469 ms - 16
GET /api/events/list 200 11.117 ms - 97
    ✓ should POST an edit to existing event (70ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2
GET /api/events/list 200 14.007 ms - 109
POST /api/events/edit 404 10.613 ms - 42
GET /api/events/list 200 7.941 ms - 109
    ✓ should NOT POST an edit to inexisting event (82ms)
DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started
    1) "before each" hook for "should DELETE existing event"


  10 passing (32s)
  1 failing

  1) Events "before each" hook for "should DELETE existing event":
     Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The `DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook ...` lines come from my `test/events.js` code (below). I noticed that in failing "beforeEach" hook it prints only line `DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started`, but not line `... hook connected`. So is there something wrong with these connects to the Postgres database?

I checked out my PostgreSQL log file, and noticed this timeout error causes this line to the log:

```
LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

So, what is going on!

Here is my code for `test/events.js`:

```js
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

var pg = require('pg');
let server = require('../app.js');
let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Events', () => {

  beforeEach((done) => { // Create some data to the database

    try {

      console.log('DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook started');

      pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
        console.log('DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook connected');

        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          done(err);

        } else {
          client.query('DELETE FROM events', function(err, result) {

            console.log('DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 1');
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              done(err);

            } else {
              client.query(' \
              INSERT INTO events (title) VALUES \
              (\'Fantastic title!\'), \
              (\'Another fantastic title!\')', function(err, result) {

                console.log('DEBUG: "beforeEach" hook queried 2');

                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  done(err);

                } else {
                  done();
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });

    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

  });

  it('should GET all the events', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/api/events/list')
    .end((err, res) => {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.body.should.be.an('object');
      res.body.success.should.equal(true);
      res.body.data.should.be.a('array');
      res.body.data.length.should.be.eql(2);

      res.body.data[0].should.be.an('object');
      res.body.data[0].title.should.equal('Fantastic title!');
      res.body.data[1].should.be.an('object');
      res.body.data[1].title.should.equal('Another fantastic title!');
      done();
    });
  });

  // There are 5 more very similar it('should ...') cases.
  // I think they aren't important but tell me if I need to include them too.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merry Christmas

I got it, what you are doing is creating a new instance for a process so executing long test cases give timeout error. what you can do is assign some pool size to each instance of a process like this:-

```
pg.defaults.poolSize
```

and one more thing you are connecting to the DB every time you execute query. put done(); after client.query line.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `doneConnect` parameter to callback of `pg.connect`, and then adding `doneConnect();` to places where `done();` is, made this work! Merry Christmas!